# how do I change the default font for different languages in Safari on a Mac?

Tags: fonts, safari, language

how do I change the default font for different languages in Safari on a Mac? Unlike Firefox, where you can specify the default sans-serif, serif, and monospace fonts for each language, in Safari you can only set the non-monospace and monospace fonts and it would be the same for all languages. Is there a way to modify this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a question for http://superuser.com/.